# Iptables doesn't open port 53

Tags: linux, iptables, bind

I have been trying different ways of opening the port but for some reason doesn't work.

The last set of lines that I have used is as follows:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -I INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT  
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have a plesk installed on my server, so it should handled dns for me. I have accessed the components page within Plesk and I can see BIND Support switched on. But, for some reason after I had a memory problem on the server DNS stopped functioning. So I gave server provider a call and all they could tell me is that port 53 is blocked and I have to unblock it, so i had to disable iptables. however for some reason after another restart DNS is back running, port 53 is open.

Comment: We can tell you nothing from individual lines, because `iptables` rules are position-dependent.  Please cut-and-paste the entire outout of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question.

Comment: Are you trying to accept inbound connections to a DNS server or allow outbound DNS queries originating from the host?

Comment: @MadHatter actually, these are the last lines he did and they're -I they'll be the first in the chain so it's probably ok to assume there's no preceding drops or rejects.

Comment: @Sirex There's more than just the `filter` table with netfilter. Actually, `iptables -L -n -v` isn't that great either IMHO - It would be preferable to give the `iptables-save` output.

Comment: yeah, that's true i guess.

Comment: @gparent I hear you, but I've found that some distros have problems with `iptables-save`, depending on configuration and suchlike.  `iptables -L -n -v` tells me where I stand **right now**.  But I admit it may come down to preference.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're running a dns server (this is serverfault after all and 'opening the port' suggests that's what you're trying to do) then your dport and sport are round the wrong way. You want --dport 53 on the INPUT chain.

You've also got the connection state tracking wrong in that case. If you only allow ESTABLISHED on input, how can anyone reach your dns server ?

Finally, if you're not running a dns server, but instead are attempting to allow yourself to *use* a dns server, these rules are totally wrong :-)

Comment: I got a plesk installed on my server, so it should have really handled dns for me, i have accessed the components page and I can see BIND Support. But, for some reason after I had a memory problem on the server DNS stopped functioning. So I gave server provider a call and all they could tell me is that port 53 is blocked and I have to unblock it, so i had to disable iptables. however for some reason after another restart DNS is back running, port 53 is open.